# How to deal with DIV position and height

Tags: html, css

I've been coping with a position of DIVs in a page. I added an image for that

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=0e90b7f

Mainly, 
I have a container DIV named (A) and inside I want a DIV named (B) align completely to the right and I'll have many DIVs named (C and etc...) inside the parent container DIV but all of them on the left side.

What I want is the DIV on the right named (B) must stay like in the picture and with its height as the same as the container DIV (A) with CSS. It can be possible?

I tried this CSS to my DIV (B):

```
.panelB{
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 310px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I could solve this if I add another DIV that contains all the mini divs from the left but I cannot changes this design only with CSS. So, how can I make that the all standalone divs on the left respect a prudent space and leave the right panel (B) just there on the right.

I forgot to say that in the DIV (B) there are also mini divs that a user can add to main container div named (A). I mean, there's a DIV on B and user click on it to add it automatically on the left (it means the main container (A)) So when the DIV (B) starts to lose a div, it loses its height and all the divs added on the container starts to take the place of the DIV (B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the height of the `.panelB` to expand/contract to the total height stack of the `C` block elements, you could `absolute position` `.panelB`to the right side of the screen, and set the its parent position to `relative` and add a `padding-right: width of .panelB` to it, like so ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjybvy33/)):

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    padding-right: 310px;/*width of .panelB*/
}
.a{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.right-panel{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 310px;
    background: yellow;
    min-height: 50px;/*just in case*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want the height of the container A. So, B.height = A.height

Comment: Sorry, I noticed later. Do I have to use the box-sizing? That would affect other pages? I did the yellow panel absolute position as you did but it went out from the main container overlapping other controls. So I tested with relative and works a little bit as I want but when I remove the controls from yellow panel it lose its height (relative) and this what it happens. http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=5c885af

Comment: Also noticed that I'm inheriting a parent parent div with this style: position: inherit;
margin-bottom: 8px;
font-size: 8pt;
padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
overflow: auto;    
This could be messing everything?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I did the yellow panel as absolute position again and the wrap I reduced its width to 80%. Maybe I have some issues inherited from parent DIVs in the master page. Thanks a lot!!!!.

Comment: No problem, also, the *{border-box: box-sizing}, the * symbol affects everything on the page, just to be on the safe side, you can just add, to .wrap parent box-sizing:border-box, and it would only be affected by it

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you can't see A bounds.. so lets imagine that instead (or use background-color perhaps)

[image]

all you need to do is to put panelA and panelB with

```
display:block;
float:left;
```

only when panels A and B are placed side by side you cant arrange the inner cells (C) inside your A panel

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. The Panel A is not the red border that you draw. Is the full container where the DIVs like C and B are contained.

Comment: that is the problem..inside A panel there are 2 regions: B and the red rectangle.. represent the red rectangle as a div and put it next to b with the css attributes i posted

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my post I said that I can't add another DIV aside B. That's what I said how can I make to all the divs inside the region on the red rectangle can behave as they are in a DIV without being on a DIV